# convert pdf to 2up on linux

Tags: linux, pdf

Is there a simple way to convert a PDF to a 2-up PDF so that I can send it to an uncooperative printer and have it actually come out 2-up?

I'm hoping to use commonly available linux tools. (I'm running debian FWIW.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`pdfnup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup) for this purpose. It is a part of [`pdfjam`](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam/) and used like this:

```
pdfnup document.pdf --nup 2x1 --outfile document2up.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks to this question and after years of extensive psnup and pdfnup usage I finally understand where its name comes from :-)

Comment: Note that `pdfnup` loses any hyperlinks in your document.

Answer (score 4):

[a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) can do a number of things with basically anything and print it to the printer.  It can also print things 2-up (or 4-up, or 8-up)

For your purposes:

```
a2ps file.pdf -2 -Pprinter
```

`a2ps` delegates some of it's work to `pdf2ps`, so make sure that it is installed on your system.  You also may want to look at the [a2ps man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/a2ps) if you want to do some other things with the swiss army knife which is a2ps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I can't send it directly to the printer. My braindead printer does bizarre things when instructed to print 2up. The --outfile=FILE argument to a2ps is ok, but translating to ps often causes loss of quality in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a script for this in SH, you can find it [here](https://github.com/severoraz/pdfbooklet)