# create PDF montage in vector format

Tags: linux, pdf, perl, vector-graphics

I have a folder full of images in PDF format, and I would like to merge them all into a single PDF in which there are many images on each page, but still in vector/PDF format.  The ImageMagick 'montage' command *almost* does this, but it actually converts them all to raster images first.  I want to be able to create a contact-sheet **that's still in vector format**, so I could specify 16 PDF files, and it will return a one-page PDF with 16 scaled images on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert pdf to 2up on linux](http://superuser.com/questions/17766/convert-pdf-to-2up-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript supports PDF/PS files and should maintain the vector qualities (can also rasterize as well).

> gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newName.pdf {1,2,3,4,5}.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Acrobat Pro?

1. Select all the files you want to combine.
2. Right click and select Combine supported files in Acrobat. Gives you some options in a dialog box, pretty straight forward.
3. Click Combine Files. This gives you a single pdf.

When you have the combined files in a single pdf, print using the Adobe PDF driver.
In the Print Dialog Box:

1. For Page Scaling, select Multiple pages per sheet.
2. Then specify the Pages per sheet.
3. Print. This will give you a single sheet pdf with the number of pages you specified.

Answer (score 0):

`pdflatex` with `tikz` package - see here for an example:

[graphics - Montage multiple PDF images, scaled to each other's dimensions, on a single PDF page? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126431/montage-multiple-pdf-images-scaled-to-each-others-dimensions-on-a-single-pdf)